# Delete SSL certificate in Kubernetes

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, ssl-certificate

Trying to delete an SSL certificate with:

```sh
kubectl delete cert mywebsite-tls
```

Or it's secret, with:

```sh
kubectl delete secret mywebsite-tls
```

Just causes them to be 'respawned' again:

```sh
NAME                  READY   SECRET                AGE
mywebsite-tls         False   mywebsite-tls         3s # <--- not desired
```

How can I actually delete this permanently? Alternatively, how can I force it to be re-issued?

This setup is on DigitalOcean and follows [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-nginx-ingress-with-cert-manager-on-digitalocean-kubernetes) using `cert-manager` if it helps.

Comment: Have you tried looking into the issuer with 'kubectl get issuer -A' ?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem for a while.

For me it was because I use the ingress-shim.

Check and see if you have an ingress with

spec.tls.secretName

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding the namespace parameter?

```
$ kubectl delete cert mywebsite-tls -n <cert_namespace>
```